# npm install, node-gyp rebuild error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, rebuild

I'm just starting out working with node.js and when I try `npm install` I get an error stating `Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'`. After extensive googling I still have not found the problem.

Here's the error log:

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqvne.png)

```
313 verbose stack Error: bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
313 verbose stack Exit status 1
313 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Apparaat1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
313 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
313 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
313 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Apparaat1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
313 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
313 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
313 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
313 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
314 verbose pkgid bcrypt@0.8.5
315 verbose cwd D:\Werk\W12C\we12c\W12C
316 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
317 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Apparaat1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
318 error node v5.7.0
319 error npm  v3.7.3
320 error code ELIFECYCLE
321 error bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
321 error Exit status 1
322 error Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
322 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm     installed.
322 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
322 error not with npm itself.
322 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
322 error     node-gyp rebuild
322 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project     with:
322 error     npm bugs bcrypt
322 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
322 error     npm owner ls bcrypt
322 error There is likely additional logging output above.
323 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Versions:
  node -v
  v5.7.0
  npm -v
  3.7.3

Comment: try to install node v 0.12.5

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad I'm hit back with: error Failed at the fsevents@1.0.7 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's a little bit late but the solution in node-gyp
 https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
There are 2
 different options.

1. Option 1: Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
2. Option 2: Install tools and configuration manually:

   - Visual C++ Build Environment:

     - Option 1: Install [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) using the **Default Install** option.
     - Option 2: Install [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) (or modify an existing installation) and select *Common Tools for Visual C++* during setup. This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop editions.
   - Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (`v3.x.x` is not supported), and run `npm config set python python2.7` (or see below for further instructions on specifying the proper Python version and path.)
   - Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

   If the above steps didn't work for you, please visit [Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules) for additional tips.

[Windows Vista / 7 only] requires [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)